# Selecting buttons at random in java

Tags: java, random, jbutton

How can I randomly select a java button, I am trying to create a tic-tac-toe game where the user plays the cpu or another player.  I have it working fine for 2 players but am stuck on 1 player game, I dont know if it can be done but my idea is that I just randomly select a button for the cpu check to see if its been selected previously and then assign the appropiate  x or o to the selected  square .

```
public void buttonSelected(ActionEvent click) {

    Object source = click.getSource();

    // loop through to see which button has been selected
    if(onePlayer){ 


        // User Vs CPU
        /*if((turn % 2 == 0)){// CPU Turn
            int selected;
            do {
                selected = new Random().nextInt(btnEmpty.length );
                if (chosen[selected -1] == false){
                    chosen[selected -1] = true;
                }

            }while (chosen[selected -1] == true);

            source =  Integer.valueOf(selected);
            for(int i=1; i<= btnNotSelected.length; i++) {
                if(source == btnNotSelected[i] && turn < 10) {
                    btnClicked = true; // user has selected a button
                    // Check which user selected button and insert appropriate x or y
                    btnNotSelected[i].setText("X");
                    btnNotSelected[i].setEnabled(false); // disable selected button
                    pnlPlayingField.requestFocus(); // highlight selected panel 
                }   
            } 

        }
        else{ //User Turn
            for(int i=1; i<=9; i++) {
                if(source == btnNotSelected[i] && turn < 10) {
                    btnClicked = true; // user has selected a button
                    // Check which user selected button and insert O
                    btnNotSelected[i].setText("O");
                    btnNotSelected[i].setEnabled(false);
                    chosen[i] = true;// disable selected button
                    pnlPlayingField.requestFocus(); // highlight selected panel
                }
            }

        }  */
        turn++;  
    }

    else if(twoPlayer){
        for(int i=1; i<=9; i++) {
            if(source == btnNotSelected[i] && turn < 10) {
                btnClicked = true; // user has selected a button
                // Check which user selected button and insert appropriate x or y
                if(turn % 2 == 0){
                    btnNotSelected[i].setText("X");
                }
                else{
                    btnNotSelected[i].setText("O");
                }
                btnNotSelected[i].setEnabled(false); // disable selected button
                pnlPlayingField.requestFocus(); // highlight selected panel
                turn++;
    }`
```

Comment: I am not sure but it looks pretty good to me. I think you should use just 'selected' instead of 'selected-1' for the index.

Comment: I would place all the free buttons in a List, shuffle it then pull the t most element. This eliminates the possibility of entering an infinite loop if no free spaces exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A one player tic-tac-toe game can certainly be done, and your strategy of selecting at random is fine. The first specific error in your commented out one player code is an infinite do-while loop. The condition on the loop always evaluates to true since `chosen[selected - 1]` is always true (if it is false, you set it to true right before the condition check), and therefore loops again.

Your do-while should look like this:

```
do {
    selected = new Random().nextInt(btnEmpty.length);
} while (chosen[selected - 1] == true);
chosen[selected - 1] = true;
```

That way, you are setting the chosen flag after the while loop condition.

A couple of additional issues I see with the onePlayer block:

- in the CPU turn block, the comparison between `source` (here an Integer) and `btnNotSelected[i]` (assuming a java button based on the working code in the twoPlayer block) will not work as you expect it to
- this method is called in response to a user input, which is clicking one of the buttons. The computer will not provide any such input, so you should have another trigger that calls running the code for the computer's turn. The easiest one is just to run it after the user's turn

Without making any drastic changes to your overall coding style and strategy, I'll attempt to translate the onePlayer portion into something more functional:

```
public void buttonSelected(ActionEvent click) {

    Object source = click.getSource();

    if (onePlayer) {

        // User's turn first
        source.setText("O");
        source.setEnabled(false);
        pnlPlayingField.requestFocus();

        // Mark that button as chosen
        for (int i = 0; i < btnNotSelected.length; i++) {
            if (source == btnNotSelected[i]) {
                chosen[i] = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        // Increment turn counter
        turn++;

        // Check if game is over
        if (turn > 9) return;

        // CPU turn
        int selected;
        do {
            selected = new Random().nextInt(btnNotSelected.length);
        } while (chosen[selected]);

        chosen[selected] = true;
        btnNotSelected[selected].setText("X");
        btnNotSelected[selected].setEnabled(false);
        pnlPlayingField.requestFocus();
        turn++;

    } else if (twoPlayer) {
        /* your preexisting twoPlayer code */
    }

}
```

Comment: This works perfect only I had to change source.setText("O"); to ((AbstractButton) source).setText("O"); and change source.setEnabled(false); to ((Component) source).setEnabled(false);  but I don't understand why, Eclipse flagged it and changed it automatically.

Comment: Glad it worked! The reason for those casting errors is that `source` is declared as type `Object`, and the `Object` class doesn't have the `setText()` or `setEnabled()` methods. The class you are using for the buttons does have those methods, so perhaps a cleaner way to fix that error is to change the type of `source` to `AbstractButton` (or whatever class you use for your buttons). Eclipse's fixes are handy, and work in this case, but it's always good practice to understand the issues yourself so you know the exact behavior of the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
int selected;
do {
       selected = new Random().nextInt(btnEmpty.length );
       if (chosen[selected -1] == false){
          chosen[selected -1] = true;
       }

}while (chosen[selected -1] == true);
```

code above is an endless loop, change it to:

```
int selected;
do {
    selected = new Random().nextInt(btnEmpty.length);
}while (chosen[selected] == true);
chosen[selected] == true;
```

remove -1, because nextInt(n) will give you a number "between 0 (inclusive) and n (exclusive)"

Answer (score 0):

I, personally, would start out with a `List` of the buttons, removing each on as it become selected, this would make easier to determine what has being selected and what hasn't, but lets work with what we've got...

```
List<Integer> free = new ArrayList<Integer>(chosen.length);
for (int index = 0; index < chosen.length; index++) {
    if (!chosen[index]) {
        free.add(index);
    }
}

if (!free.isEmpty()) {
    Collections.shuffle(free);
    int selected = free.get(0);

    // Continue with game logic
}
```

Basically, this places an `Integer` in a `List` which represents the "free" slots.  We then use `Collections.shuffle` to randomise the list, then we grab the first element (for want of something to grab) and continue with the game logic...

This eliminates the possibility of a infinite loop trying to find free slots that don't exist...